# Interview question: difference between object and object-oriented languages

Tags: oop, programming-languages

My friend was asked the following question: what's the difference between object language and object-oriented language?

It's a little unintelligible question. What does term «object language» correspond to? Does that mean «pure» object-oriented language, like the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) says:

> Languages called "pure" OO languages, because everything in them is treated consistently as an object, from primitives such as characters and punctuation, all the way up to whole classes, prototypes, blocks, modules, etc. They were designed specifically to facilitate, even enforce, OO methods. Examples: Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ruby, JADE, VB.NET.

Comment: Lame interview question.

Comment: What I would think of as object language is what ".o" or ".obj" files are written in. I suspect this is not what the interviewer meant.

Comment: @David Thornley- wouldn't that be object files in machine language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless the person was interviewed by a philosopher talking about an abstract metalanguage, or an old-school engineer talking about the end result a compiler produces, the question sounds like semantic masturbation by someone who doesn't speak the same language as the rest of the industry.

So in other words, the distinction is whatever the interviewer wants it to be. (Or perhaps the question was misheard). I don't think most developers would think that the terms are connected enough to be worthy of comparison and contrast.

The right response would probably be in the style of a psychoanalyst: What do you think it means? Ask clarifying questions to make sure you understand what the interviewer is asking and assuming. Then leave and don't call the employer back, because you don't want to work there.

Comment: I guess some old-school Smalltalker wanted the interviewee to say that there are *pure* and *unpure* OO languages... As much as I like OO and think this distinction is important, vague terminology is bad excuse, better could be question about benefits of *pure* OO.

Comment: I'd be all for an abstract, architecture astronaut discussion of OO purity in an interview, because it would reveal a lot more about the candidate (and probably the interviewer), but asking people to compare and contrast a term in wide use with one that nobody uses is a different burden entirely.

Comment: +1 for an awesome answer and a weird interview question

Answer (score 4):

- The term *object* does not have an official, widely used or otherwise well-known definition.
- The term *object language* does not have an official, widely used or otherwise well-known definition.
- The term *object-oriented* does have an official definition, but that is usually completely ignored, not widely used nor otherwise well-known.
- The term *object-oriented language* does not have a single official, widely used or otherwise well-known definition, it is usually understood to mean

  - a language in which object-oriented programming is possible or
  - a language in which *only* object-oriented programming is possible or
  - a language in which object-oriented programming is easy or
  - a language in which object-oriented programming is easy and non-object-oriented programming is hard or
  - a language in which everything is an object or
  - any combination of the above or
  - something completely different (and note that in any of the above you can substitute arbitrary definitions for "object" and "object-oriented")

In short: the interview question roughly translates to "what's the difference between this thing I'm not going to tell you what it is and that other thing I'm also not going to tell you what it is?"

Comment: Agreed. Sounds like «Go there, don't know where and bring that, don't know what».

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that the interviewer was looking for a distinction between [object-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based) and [object oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This is, for example, using structs in C, with no polymorphism or inheritance.

The difference between the two for C and C++ is highlighted [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.9).

Comment: Hmm, I thought that object oriented programming languages could be subdivided among others into class-based and prorotype-based, however the object-based Wikipedia article those not correspond...